# MSSQL to MYSQL one way data syncing

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, migration

i have one MySQL server.
in that server there are the 15 databases and i need to sync the data to MsSQL to MySQL and the condition is a data transmit only MsSQL to MySQL on every update. so please guide me how to perform this task and how to set cron job.

Comment: Add details of things you have tried. Some more details about what you want to achieve will be helpful too.

Comment: we already use Mysql benchmark and use migration option...but it cant work...I want to use synchronization option but i cant found...please tell me in which version i found "Synchronize With Any Source" option...for more information https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-database-synchronization.html.....

Comment: your subject line is saying that mssql to mysql but in body you are saying that mysql to mysql...first clear it....further if you want to sync from mssql to mysql then you can use link method which is available in mssql but you can't do from mysql to mssql....